# Quadratic Equation ( x and y ) formula

Tags: quadratics

There's a formula for solving a Quadratic Equation that has $x$ as a variable; e.g:

$$2x^2 + 5x - 8x = 0$$

**Step 1** (is to find delta/discriminant):

$\Delta = b^2 - 4ac$

**Step 2** (is to find $x_1$ and $x_2$):

$x$ = $\dfrac{-(b) \pm \sqrt\Delta}{2a}$

---

My question is... Is it possible to solve an equation which has $x$ & $y$  variables, with the formula above? Or is there another formula for equations with $x$ & $y$ variables?

Example:

$$2x^2 + 5xy - 8y^2 = 0$$

Comment: To solve an equation with two variables, we need two equations in the first place. With your example, you could solve for $x$ and your answers would have a $y$ in them, or solve for $y$ where the ansswers would have an $x$ in them. There is no way to solve this equation for $x$ and $y$ as it stands now

Comment: We could either treat it as a quadratic in $x$, where $a=2$, $b=5y$ and $c=-8y^2$, or a quadratic in $y$ where $a=-8$, $b=5x$ and $c=2x^2$

Comment: An equation of the form $ax^2+by^2+cxy+dx+ey+f=0$ has in general infinitely many solutions. It describes a conic: a circle, an ellipse, a parabola, ... See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section

Answer (score 1):

Going off of @lioness99a's comment, for your example you can set $a=2$, $b=5y$, and $c=-8y^2$ to get

\begin{align*} x &= \frac{-5y \pm \sqrt{(5y)^2 - 4\cdot 2 \cdot (-8y^2)}}{2\cdot 2} \\
&= \frac{-5y \pm \sqrt{89}|y|}{4} \\
&= \frac{1}{4} (-5 \pm \sqrt{89})y
\end{align*}

or fix $x$ and treat $y$ as the variable.

Comment: Because of the $\pm$, you could use just $y$ instead of $|y|$. and get $x =  = \frac{-5 \pm \sqrt{89}}{4}y$

Comment: thanks, I didn't notice that

Answer (score 0):

HINT: if $$y=0$$ and $$x=0$$ are not a solutions of your equation you can write
$$2\frac{x}{y}+5-8\frac{y}{x}=0$$ Setting $t=x/y$ you will have
$$2t+5-\frac{8}{t}=0$$ multiplying by $t$:
$$2t^2+5t-8=0$$

Comment: How does this help find the values of $x$ and $y$? You can solve this for $t$ and then you are still left with an equation of the form $\frac xy=t$ to solve. Also, in the example, $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is a solution to the equation

Comment: if you have for example $$x/y=5$$ then is $$x=5y$$ and you can solve your equation for $y$ and then you have $x$